# Register app among navigation apps in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, url-scheme

How do i register / make my app receive implicit navigation requests from user. ?

lets say i have app "A" which is capable of providing routing and navigation.

i have tried adding comgooglemaps scheme to my apps url scheme..but it doesnt list my app in the selection list..what it does is open my app when google maps is not installed

now when someuser requests navigation through some third party apps,i need the system to list my app among the apps that provides navigation facility.

i was able to achieve this in android by listening for navigation intents...

please help me in doing same in iOS in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its not the system which lists the navigation apps.

Its the developers who checks the list of available apps in the phone using the preferred list of apps and their corresponding urlSchemes then show the list of navigation applications.